# Moving Kinetic Sprites to a specific point

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

```
<script>
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: 800,
            height: 600
        });

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        var image = new Image();
        var image2 = new Image();
        var newX = 500;
        var animations = {
        pos1: [{
            x: 32,
            y: 32,
            width: 32,
            height: 32
            },
            {
            x: 64,
            y: 32,
            width: 32,
            height: 32
            },
            {
            x: 96,
            y: 32,
            width: 32,
            height: 32
            },{
            x: 128,
            y: 32,
            width: 32,
            height: 32
            },
            {
            x: 160,
            y: 32,
            width: 32,
            height: 32
            },
            {
            x: 32,
            y: 0,
            width: 32,
            height: 32
            },],



        };

        image.onload = function() {

            var anim = new Kinetic.Sprite({
                x: 100,
                y: 100,
                image: image,
                animation: 'pos1',
                animations: animations,
                frameRate: 10
                });
            layer.add(anim);

            stage.add(layer);
            anim.start();

        };



    //image.src = 'myimgsrc';
</script>
```

That starts a Sprite animation. Its a character which is able to do a walk animation and now i want to get him from one point to another maybe with a button or something.. 
My Question now is, how can i move this sprite slowly with the animation from x = 100 to 
x = 700 and stop the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use transitionTo for moving:

```
anim.transitionTo({
  x : 200,
  duration: 3
 });
```

If you need to stop sprite animation after moving:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  anim.stop();
},3000);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/7C6Mn/